# jqMath highlight box like bbox in MathJax/MathJs

Tags: javascript, mathjax, jqmath

Does jqmath have support for adding custom containers inside of final render?

Basically is there any equivalent to bbox in MathJax/MathJs http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/tex.html#bbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\id` and `\cl` macros will give a subexpression an id or class, and you can then style it with CSS. For example, `\id "some-id" {x+y}` or `x + \cl "some-class" y`.