# How does one indicate strikethrough in jqmath?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqmath

For example I want to show reduction of fractions to simplest terms by doing prime factorization on numerator and denominator and then showing common terms that can be eliminated.

So something like $6/8=(2)(3)/(2)(2)(2)=3/4$ but showing a strikethrough on the 2s on the top and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you use CSS, like in [jqMath highlight box like bbox in MathJax/MathJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805054/jqmath-highlight-box-like-bbox-in-mathjax-mathjs?rq=1). So write e.g. `$$6/8={\cl"cancel"{(2)}(3)}/{\cl"cancel"{(2)}(2)(2)}=3/4$$` and then add `.cancel { text-decoration: line-through }` to your style sheet.